# getting the last user defined row from the table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

i have my table like this

```
Sr_No / AccessionNo / Roll_nO   / Price
---------------------------------------    
1  /     101     /      45   /     1000

2  /     102        /   46     /   2000

3   /    101       /    43    /    500
```

i want that when user types in the textbox 2 then the last 2 rows should be retrived but i dont know which function to be used here
i am a student and started my c# quite few months before and using sql server from few months only.
i have googled that and found some query but i dont think this will be helpfull as this query gives me the top part is there any function which gives the bottom part defined by the user?

```
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM [TableName]
```

sorry for my bad english.

Comment: you need to state when you want that query to be executed.. when the user `leaves the textbox` why don't you have the `Invocation` tied to a `Button Click` event..? please show some code that you currently have so that we can understand your logical flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify an `ORDER BY ... DESC` clause to get the bottom rows:

```
SELECT TOP 5 * 
FROM [TableName]
ORDER BY Sr_No DESC;
```

Comment: sir if i want that user change the textbox value to 6 so how can i change the query???
INSERT INTO circulation (AccessionNO,rollno,) VALUES (@AccessionNO,@rollno)
i defined the scalar variable and then command.parameters.addwithvalue("@accessionno" , "textbox.text")
so here how that can be achived to change the 5??

Comment: @aquibRocks Do you want to insert these selected 5 rows into the table `circulation `? if so then use `INSERT ... INTO circulation TOP 5 * 
FROM [TableName]
ORDER BY Sr_No DESC`.

Comment: no no sir i have just given an example.. that how i take the input from the user... if according to your query if i want to change the 5 to 10 then what i have to do??? i want that user decides how much row he wants

Answer (score 0):

`TOP` will certianly work. you just need to *Reorder* the records using `ORDER BY` clause,

```
SELECT TOP 2 * FROM [TableName] ORDER BY SR_NO DESC
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0dc5e4/1)

Comment: sir how i can change the value of 2 to the user defined textbox so that user can select how many rows he wants to retrive. for example i use this
 INSERT INTO circulation (AccessionNO,rollno,) VALUES (@AccessionNO,@rollno) i defined the scalar variable and then command.parameters.addwithvalue("@accessionno" , "textbox.text")